# How can I set a specific broker for a Celery queue in Django?

Tags: django, redis, celery, amqp

I am trying to move my current resource intensive video processing queue to a separate broker. I have my default broker url set to use AMQP:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://defaultaddress/'
```

My new broker is using Redis:

```
VIDEO_BROKER_URL = 'redis://videoaddress/'
```

How can I set my 'video' queue to use the VIDEO_BROKER_URL instead of the default BROKER_URL?

I have read through [Routing Tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) in the Celery docs, but I didn't see anything on changing the broker.

Answer (score 4):

First of all it seems to be impossible in django-celery, because you have only one instance of celery app per django instance (project). But for now django-celery is deprecated and in the new concept of celery and django integration you actually can solve your problem so:

You have to create two different celery apps

**common/celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('common',
             broker='amqp://',
             include=['common.tasks'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

**common/tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from common.celery import app


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

**video/celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('video',
             broker='redis://',
             include=['video.tasks'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

**video/tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from video.celery import app


@app.task
def decode_video(path, from_format, to_format):
    # do something
```

Now you can import both apps from your django project. For example:

```py
from video.tasks import decode_video
from common.tasks import add

def some_view_function(request):
    x = add.delay(2, 2)
    decode_video.apply_async(('/1/2/3/video.mp4', 'mp4', 'avi'), countdown=5)
    # return something
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: This approach is surely the right one (that's why you get an upvote) but I would in general discourage the usage of different brokers, as the broker is made to take benefit of centralized routing and queue management. I don't see the benefits of using 2 brokers. You could maybe state this in your answer to make it more complete, if you agree.

Answer (score 0):

So after doing some more searching, I came across this:

```
from kombu import BrokerConnection

...

video_connection = BrokerConnection(settings.VIDEO_BROKER_URL)
process_video.apply_async(arg=[video_pk], connection=video_connection)
```

My initial testing seems to be working, as my local instance of celeryd is not picking up the task.